# Deflater.deflate and small output buffers

Tags: java, deflate

I'm seeing a strange situation with small output buffers with Java 8u45 and the [`java.util.Deflater.deflate(byte[] b, int off, int len, int flush)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#deflate-byte:A-int-int-int-) method when used with small output buffers.

(I'm working on some low level networking code related to WebSocket's upcoming `permessage-deflate` extension, so small buffers are a reality for me)

The example code:

```java
package deflate;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;

public class DeflaterSmallBufferBug
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean nowrap = true;
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,nowrap);

        byte[] input = "Hello".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.printf("input is %,d bytes - %s%n",input.length,getHex(input,0,input.length));

        deflater.setInput(input);

        byte[] output = new byte[input.length];

        // break out of infinite loop seen with bug
        int maxloops = 10;

        // Compress the data
        while (maxloops-- > 0)
        {
            int compressed = deflater.deflate(output,0,output.length,Deflater.SYNC_FLUSH);
            System.out.printf("compressed %,d bytes - %s%n",compressed,getHex(output,0,compressed));

            if (compressed < output.length)
            {
                System.out.printf("Compress success");
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("Exited compress (maxloops left %d)%n",maxloops);
    }

    private static String getHex(byte[] buf, int offset, int len)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
        hex.append('[');
        for (int i = offset; i < (offset + len); i++)
        {
            if (i > offset)
            {
                hex.append(' ');
            }
            hex.append(String.format("%02X",buf[i]));
        }
        hex.append(']');
        return hex.toString();
    }
}
```

In the above case, I'm attempting to generate compressed bytes for the input `"Hello"` using an output buffer of 5 bytes in length.

I would assume the following resulting bytes:

```
buffer 1 [ F2 48 CD C9 C9 ]
buffer 2 [ 07 00 00 00 FF ]
buffer 3 [ FF ]
```

Which translates as

```
[ F2 48 CD C9 C9 07 00 ] <-- the compressed data
[ 00 00 FF FF ]          <-- the deflate tail bytes
```

However, when `Deflater.deflate()` is used with a small buffer, this normal loop continues infinitely at 5 bytes of compressed data (seems to only manifest at buffers of 5 bytes or lower).

Resulting output of running the above demo ...

```
input is 5 bytes - [48 65 6C 6C 6F]
compressed 5 bytes - [F2 48 CD C9 C9]
compressed 5 bytes - [07 00 00 00 FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [FF 00 00 00 FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [FF 00 00 00 FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [FF 00 00 00 FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [FF 00 00 00 FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [FF 00 00 00 FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [FF 00 00 00 FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [FF 00 00 00 FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [FF 00 00 00 FF]
Exited compress (maxloops left -1)
```

If you make the input/output larger than 5 bytes then the problem seems to go away.  (Just make the input string `"Hellox"` to test this for yourself)

Results of making the buffer 6 bytes (input as `"Hellox"`)

```
input is 6 bytes - [48 65 6C 6C 6F 78]
compressed 6 bytes - [F2 48 CD C9 C9 AF]
compressed 6 bytes - [00 00 00 00 FF FF]
compressed 5 bytes - [00 00 00 FF FF]
Compress success
```

Even these results are bit quirky to me, as it seems there's 2 deflate tail-byte sequences present.

So, I guess my ultimate question is, am I missing something about the `Deflater` usage that making thing odd for me, or is this pointing at a possible bug in the JVM `Deflater` implementation itself?

**Update: Aug 7, 2015**

This discovery has been accepted as [bugs.java.com/JDK-8133170](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8133170)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a zlib "feature", documented in zlib.h:

> In the case of a Z_FULL_FLUSH or Z_SYNC_FLUSH, make sure that
>   avail_out is greater than six to avoid repeated flush markers due to
>   avail_out == 0 on return.

What is happening is that each call of `deflate()` with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` is inserting a five-byte flush marker.  Since you are not providing enough output space to get the marker, you call again to get more output, but are asking it to insert *another* flush marker at the same time.

What you should be doing is calling `deflate()` with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` *once*, and then getting all of the available output with additional `deflate()` calls, if necessary, that use `Z_NO_FLUSH` (or `NO_FLUSH` in Java).

Comment: Dang! Mark Adler responded to my question, hard to get a more authoritative answer then this. :-)

Comment: Guess I should file an apidoc bug with Oracle to add this tidbit to the Deflater documentation.  Seems useful to know.

Comment: It should be considered a "bug", right? Why does zlib do it? To save a flag?

Comment: Perhaps.  It depends on what you would expect such a call to mean and do.  When you call `deflate()` with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` or `Z_FULL_FLUSH`, you are requesting that deflate insert an empty stored block in the stream.  So shouldn't it insert an empty stored block for every such call?  Alternatively, deflate could ignore your subsequent requests for the insertion of a marker until you have consumed the output that contains the first one you requested.  Either way you could claim that it's a bug.